# Is octonion structure related to the fact that an 8-cube has an equal number of 2-faces and 3-cells?

Tags: octonions

Background:
We know that octonions exist in 8-space, and we know that in 8-space, the 8-dimensional "measure polytope" ("hypercube") just so happens to have the SAME number of 2-dimensional faces (squares) and 3-dimensional cells (cubes). (This number is 1792,)  Further, Walter Nissen has stated (and proved) the relevant general property of CERTAIN n-cubes (n=2,5,8,11,...) at this link:

http://upforthecount.com/math/hypercubes.html

Question:
So my question is the following. Is this property of the "8-cube" (i.e. the property of having the same number of square faces and cubic cells) related in any way to the structure of octonions and/or the permissible operations on octonions?

Comment: Is the 8-dimensional space of opinions isomorphois with that containing the hypercube?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Oscar.  Don't know the answer to your question, but I agree it's a good initial question to ask.  The 8-cube of course picks out 2**8 points in Euclidean 8-space (the vertices of the 8-cube), so I think you're right to ask how these relate to octonions.  If they don't in any way, then the answer to the question is probably "no".

Comment: Sorry for the mistypes I just saw.  Working from a phone.

Comment: I see no relationship whatsoever. Furthermore, the link illustrates the fact this phenomenon occurs in every dimension of the form $d=3n+2$, not just $8$.

Comment: Thanks for what seems to be a definitive answer, "anon". However, I do want to observed that  the possibility of the relationship is NOT logically ruled out by the fact that "dimensional degeneracy" is perfectlty general, i.e. not restricted to the case of 2 and 3 within 8.

Comment: On the other hand, "anon", this link suggests the relationship MAY be there:  http://tony5m17h.net/Weyl.html  In particular, see this passage:    •The128 vertices of the odd 8-dimensional half-HyperCube with graded structure 8 56 56 8 correspond to 128 of the 240 E8 root vectors as follows: ◦8 to the 8 octonion vector space basis elements, with positive sign;
◦8 to the 8 octonion vector space basis elements, with negative sign;
◦56+56 = 112 to the 112 vectors with non-zero components on the octonion real axis;

Comment: It is important to note that the "6.4" degeneracy we're discussing here (same number of 3-cells and 2-faces in the 8-cube MAY be related to the "6,4" degeneracy which allows E6 to be "folded" into F4.  I say this because modern work tends to see E6 as a subgroup of E8.